# iPhone: change view when selevting a table cell which is in a tabbar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with 2 views. 
One view contains a UITable. When I am selecting a cell I want to navigate to another view.

I always did it with this code:

```
 if(self.damageController == nil)
    {

        DamageControllerOverview *viewTwo = [[DamageControllerOverview alloc] initWithNibName:@"DamageControllerOverview" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


        self.damageController = viewTwo;
        self.damageController.damageAccount = damageAccount;
        self.damageController.ma = ma;

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

        temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
        temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;

        [viewTwo release];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.damageController animated:YES];
```

But since I have the table in the Tabbar it is not working anymore.
Does anybody know why?

Best regards
Melanie

*Edit:
this is not my rootviewcontroller.
I already have a navigationcontroller and don't want to create a new one in the tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your question is that

1- you have a `tabbar` in the main window
2-then you have a `navigationController` in the tabbar.

so you need to push your controller to the `navigationController` this way.

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:self.damageController animated:YES];
```

instead of
[`self.navigationController pushViewController:self.damageController animated:YES];`

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi. I don't have a navigationController in my tabbar. I have a navigationController in my rootview. (which is not the view with tha tabbar) Do I need a second navigationController for the tabbar?

Comment: Yes you must add the navigationController fist to the tabbar and than push your roort controller to it. Currently if you push a viewController directly to the tabbar it won't give you the functionality for the navigating.

Comment: Currently the self.navigationController will be nil since you don't have your viewController in any stack to infact you are calling oushViewController on a nil navigationController thats why it don't get pushed. Link to the ViewController Class Refrences is given below please check the navigationController property section to get the basic understanding about the navigationController fo a view Controller http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: ok.. i googled a lot. but i have no idea how to store my viewcontroller in any stack.. 
So again, I have a tabbar and my first view shows an tableview. in this tableview I want to select a cell and this cell navigates me to another view. My Storyboard is Dashboard->Tabbar->tableview->Detail. I have a navigationcontroller in Dashboard. Do I need a new one for the Tabbar? Or can I use the same? and if yes, how?

Comment: You need to a navigation controller in the tab bar controller for each tab. In the appDelegate where you set the tabbar viewControllers array instead of pushing your controller with the table view push a navigation controller to the tabbar and then push your controller with table view as a root controller to that navigation controller. After that when user tap on the cell navigate  the way as explained in the answer above. I hope its clear for you now